# How to include Rd2pdf latex file as appendix in document

Tags: appendices, include, r

I Have created an R package, I want to include the documentation as an appendix in my Thesis document. To create the latex file I did the following (I am partly including this to make it easier for others).

```
Rd2pdf "path to my package folder" --no-clean
```

The no-clean option was used to make sure that the temporary latex files were not removed. These late files were stored in a hidden "Rd2pdf" folder on the same path that the pdf was saved to (on Linux ubuntu this was the home folder).

However, getting latex file to integrate with my latex document is challenging. the Rd2pdf latex file relies on a Rd.sty file I can't find. I don't know if even if I can find Rd.sty whether it will mess up the formatting on the rest of the document.

How what methods can I use to integrate the Rd2pdf latex file into my larger latex document causing minimal problems to the original document. Ideally I won't just include it as a pdf using `\usepackage{pdfpages}` and `\includepdf[pages=-]{myfile.pdf}` but I will as a last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify what the setup of your thesis document is (which documentclass, how appendices are made etc.) so it is difficult to say if there are compatibility issues with your exact setup.

However, with regular documentclasses it is not too difficult to combine a document with R documentation, by removing a few things from the output of Rd2pdf.

As an example I took the file `load.Rd` from the tutorial on https://colinfay.me/writing-r-extensions/writing-r-documentation-files.html. This results in the following `.tex` file (only the top is shown):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[times,inconsolata,hyper]{Rd}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[utf8,latin1]{inputenc}
% \usepackage{graphicx} % @USE GRAPHICX@
\makeindex{}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{}
\begin{center}
{\textbf{\huge \R{} documentation}} \par\bigskip{{\Large of \file{load.Rd}}}
\par\bigskip{\large \today}
\end{center}
\inputencoding{utf8}
\HeaderA{load}{Reload Saved Datasets}{load}
\keyword{file}{load}
% etc.
```

You need to remove the document structure (`\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`) from this file. Then you copy the packages to your main document. The main package (`\usepackage{Rd}`) has font options that change the appearance of the document, which can be removed (`times` and `inconsolata`). That is basically it, then you just copy the rest of the generated `.tex` file into your own document.

Assume you have the following main document:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\section{Dolor sit amet}
\begin{appendices}
\chapter*{Appendix: documentation}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Then the full file becomes as follows:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
% following two packages are copied from the generated .tex file
\usepackage[hyper]{Rd}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\section{Dolor sit amet}
\begin{appendices}
\chapter*{Appendix: documentation}
% content from the generated file starts here
\begin{center}
{\textbf{\huge \R{} documentation}} \par\bigskip{{\Large of \file{load.Rd}}}
\par\bigskip{\large \today}
\end{center}
\inputencoding{utf8}
\HeaderA{load}{Reload Saved Datasets}{load}
\keyword{file}{load}
% etc.
```

Screenshot from the page where the appendix starts:

[image]

Note that the `Rd.sty` file is in the search path of LaTeX (otherwise Rd2pdf would not succeed). Therefore you don't need to locate it yourself or place it in any specific directory. However, if you want to know where it is you can use `kpsewhich Rd.sty` in the terminal, which will return the path.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. I get some strange formatting issues but these are probably related to the format the my university uses.